# Social Feed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, feed

I have a **Post** model with tables columns (id, user_id and post)
Then i have **post_shared_with**  with columns (id, post_id and user_id(the user the post is shared with)). There is currently no model for this table, i just need it to keep track of who the post is shared with. A post can be shared with many people.
Then i have the same scheme for **Photos**. Model Photos with table columns (id, user_id and photo_path). table **photo_shared_with** has no model and has columns (id, photo_id,user_id).
And finally, the same old scheme for videos.
Questions:
I need a page to display all the posts, photos and videos together in one feed. Lets say controller feed, how do i get the sorted feed in the database? and what would my view look like?
Secondly, is this even a efficient way of going about this? should i use a front end framework like backbone to handle feed Or is there a better way to structure things like this?
Really sorry if this is a super basic stuff, i'm a newb and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Nb: i have finished the railstutorial book by micheal hartl so i know the basics.

Comment: check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/406-public-activity
There's also a pro episode that show you how to do it from scratch.

Comment: Yh thanks but this is a bit different.

Comment: Sounds like you should just try something before posting to SO. You have some ideas in your question try them out.

Comment: I don't know how to go about it and i don't know if what i've done so far is efficient. I wouldn't ask if i knew, also i'm not really asking for code, just a notch in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a shared_with table that's polymorphic (so it can belong to any object). Then you'd just query the shared_with table.

So your schema would look like:

```
Post (id, user_id, post_content)
Photo (id, user_id, photo_path)
SharedWith(id, shareable_id, shareable_type, user_id) (where the user_id is who you're sharing this with).
```

Here's a link about polymorphic joins using rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations for reference.

Comment: After writing this answer, a more appropriate name for SharedWith might be Feed, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one gem to deal with social feed feature https://github.com/SharpV/sharp_social, hope it could help you .